# Col1:15 -18 First Born

Tags: contradiction

Col1:15 -18 First Born. Are you saying that the words Supremacy and First Born are synonymous? Are all firstborns considered supreme?
Why didn't Paul just use the word supremacy? The question that arises in Colossians and other scriptures that use the word firstborn is not whether Jesus is supreme, but why did Paul and John use the word firstborn. John 1:1-14 is synonymous with Colossians 1:1 Paul and John were talking about the birth an life of Jesus Christ. The Word (God) became flesh. The Last Adam was the first Born of all creation. The first Adam was created. The only two humans to have had unblemished blood flowing through their veins. I forward to hearing from you. JIL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are the two references to 'firstborn' connected?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66201/how-are-the-two-references-to-firstborn-connected)

Comment: This question has been asked many times.  See also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48812/why-does-god-refer-to-david-as-his-firstborn-psalm-8927/48813#48813  and  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48843/what-does-it-mean-for-christ-to-be-firstborn-from-the-dead/48845#48845 etc

Comment: When you write, "Are you saying that...", who is this 'you'? Who said that "the words Supremacy and First Born are synonymous?" A citation is needed, with references, and a name or two. Then, at the end, when you say you look "forward to hearing from you. JIL." do you mean the anonymous person at the start, or what? This Q reads as if it is a copy and paste from somewhere else, so explanations are needed for the community to make sense  of it.

Answer (score 0):

Paul details that Christ was the "creator of all things".  He is a part of the "determinate counsel" (Acts 2:23) that existed prior to our universe.  He Himself then existed **prior** to His **physical birth**.

**Colossians 1:15-19**

> "Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every creature:
> 16 For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him:
> 17 And he is before all things, and by him all things consist.
> 18 And he is the head of the body, the church: who is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead; that in all things he might have the preeminence.
> 19 For it pleased the Father that in him should all fulness dwell;"

**1 Corinthians 15:42-49**

> "So also is the resurrection of the dead. It is sown in corruption; it is raised in incorruption:
> 43 It is sown in dishonour; it is raised in glory: it is sown in weakness; it is raised in power:
> 44 It is sown a natural body; it is raised a spiritual body. There is a natural body, and there is a spiritual body.
> 45 And so it is written, The first man Adam was made a living soul; the last Adam was made a quickening spirit.
> 46 Howbeit that was not first which is spiritual, but that which is natural; and afterward that which is spiritual.
> 47 The first man is of the earth, earthy; the second man is the Lord from heaven.
> 48 As is the earthy, such are they also that are earthy: and as is the heavenly, such are they also that are heavenly.
> 49 And as we have borne the image of the earthy, we shall also bear the image of the heavenly."

The physical firstborn is then not necessarily "supreme" to the next physical born.  In fact, it is quite opposite.  Cain the disobedient, then Abel the obedient.  Ishmael, then Issac.  Esau, then Jacob.  King Saul, then David.  Saul of Tarsus (fleshly minded), then converted to Paul (spiritually minded).  National Israel, the unbelieving, and eventual believing Israel that will then receive her long-awaited kingdom of heaven.

This is no different than our own physical birth and into the sin-nature that passed down to us from Adam, who was of the flesh and corruptible.  We hear the gospel of our salvation (our way out of this carnal life and into God's eternal and incorruptible presence), we believe the gospel, and we are then "sealed" by and with the Spirit (**Ephesians 1:13, 4:30**) and into the spiritual body of Christ.

**Romans 10:1-4**

> "Brethren, my heart's desire and prayer to God for Israel is, that they might be saved.
> 2 For I bear them record that they have a zeal of God, but not according to knowledge.
> 3 For they being ignorant of God's righteousness, and going about to establish their own righteousness, have not submitted themselves unto the righteousness of God.
> 4 For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to every one that believeth."

We have placed our faith in the physical perfection of Jesus Christ and His shed blood as the atonement to God for our sins because of our inability to meet God's required righteousness on our own accord.  Christ's perfection is then imputed to us upon having faith alone in Him and His righteousness.  It is when we understand that God accepted Jesus Christ and we then accept Jesus Christ being God's perfection in our stead.

**Romans 4:23-25**

> "Now it was not written for his sake alone, that it was imputed to him;
> 24 But for us also, to whom it shall be imputed, if we believe on him that raised up Jesus our Lord from the dead;
> 25 Who was delivered for our offences, and was raised again for our justification."

We will struggle with the remainder of this physical life in mortifying our old **carnal** fleshly desires, and now allowing (quenching not) the Spirit to guide us in our new **spiritual** walk in faith, as Paul perfectly describes below.

**Romans 7:14-25**

> "For we know that the law is spiritual: but I am carnal, sold under sin.
> 15 For that which I do I allow not: for what I would, that do I not; but what I hate, that do I.
> 16 If then I do that which I would not, I consent unto the law that it is good.
> 17 Now then it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me.
> 18 For I know that in me (that is, in my flesh,) dwelleth no good thing: for to will is present with me; but how to perform that which is good I find not.
> 19 For the good that I would I do not: but the evil which I would not, that I do.
> 20 Now if I do that I would not, it is no more I that do it, but sin that dwelleth in me.
> 21 I find then a law, that, when I would do good, evil is present with me.
> 22 For I delight in the law of God after the inward man:
> 23 But I see another law in my members, warring against the law of my mind, and bringing me into captivity to the law of sin which is in my members.
> 24 O wretched man that I am! who shall deliver me from the body of this death?
> 25 I thank God through Jesus Christ our Lord. So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin."

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question!

Answer (score 0):

OP's question 1st question;

> Col1:15 -18 First Born. Are you saying that the words Supremacy and First Born are synonymous?

No, supremacy and firstborn are not synonymous.

> 2nd question;
> "Are all firstborns considered supreme? "

First borns are not always supreme.  Look at the example of Esau and Jacob. The inheritance was to go to Esau because he was the first born. That was customary for the first born to get double inheritance, and the blessings.
Instead, it was given to the second born.

> 3rd question;
> Why didn't Paul just use the word supremacy?

> The word supremacy means;
> : highest in rank or authority
> the supreme commander
> especially : in a position of unquestioned authority, dominance.

Even though the first born here has all these qualities, He has been gifted from the Father, who owns all things first.  He is showing a  love relationship between the Father and the son.  Everything comes from the Father first

Who has first given to God,
that God should repay him?”
For from Him and through Him and to Him are all things. Romans 11:35-36

> So getting back to the last question;
> "Why didn't Paul just use the word supremacy?"

Perhaps it is because the Father so loves His Son and wants to give him everything.
He is just not supreme and a dictator, but is filled with His Father's love that He passes on to His creation.

I think the Father's heart is reflected in the story of Abraham, having everything, but does not a son to inherit his everything.  It meant more for Abraham to have his very own son that he could give an inheritance to.

> But Abram replied, “O Sovereign LORD, what good are all your blessings when I don’t even have a son? Since you’ve given me no children, Eliezer of Damascus, a servant in my household, will inherit all my wealth. Genesis. 15:2

> Abraham left everything he owned to Isaac.   Genesis 5:5

> My master’s wife Sarah has borne him a son in her old age, and my master has given him everything he owns.  Genesis 24:36

Next question;

> "The question that arises in Colossians and other scriptures that use the word firstborn
> is not whether Jesus is supreme,
> but why did Paul and John use the word firstborn. "

God wants to keep identifying who His  Son is by also calling Him first born in everything. His identity reflects who God is and the therefore seen in His Son.

> In these last days he has spoken to us by a Son,whom he appointed heir of all things, through whom he also created the ages. He is the reflection of God’s glory and the exact imprint of God’s very being, and he sustains all things by his powerful word. When he had made purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high, having become as much superior to angels as the name he has inherited is more excellent than theirs. Hebrews 1:2-4

The Father has entrusted the Firstborn with everything that has come from Him.

The Father wants all to honor His Son and make sure everyone knows who His first born is.

> that all may honor the Son according as they honor the Father; he who is not honoring the Son, does not honor the Father who sent Him. John 5:23

There is great significance of being called the first born:

> "The laws and customs of all nations show that to be “firstborn” means, not only priority in time, but a certain superiority in privilege and authority."
> In the Old Testament, the firstborn son was the one who normally received a double inheritance, and was the one who would inherit his father’s role as head of the family."
> Quoted  from Bible . Org questions

Comment: Just a to note add. The Bible never ever refers to Jesus as the First Born Son of God. He is referred to as the only begotten Son   Colossians 1:15 refers to the virgin both of Jesus as John wrote almost word for word  in John1:1-14. This goes along with Jesus being called the Last Adam and second man. These tiles and more are all tied to the humanity of Jesus and the amazing Plan of God. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @David Jasurda . Your comment made me look again at this verse in Hebrews 1:6 more closely.  again, when He brings his firstborn into the world, he says, "Let all God's angels worship Him. This definitely was a humiliated form that the Son of God did take on.  He certainly was the first born of God through a woman and God's spirit.  And of course, then the first born out from the dead.

Comment: I would suggest reading other translations as scholars are only humans and have to discern what God is saying in his word just like you and I . God’s Son has always existed with His father. As stated in Col1:17. He is before all things, and in Him all things hold together  He came to earth as Human.

Comment: Jesus was called the Last Adam as he was the only human to be Born with unblemished blood. The First Adam was the only human to be Created with unblemished blood. Col 1:15 is talking about about the Last Adam’s birth.

Comment: @David Jasurda , Even though Adam was the first man  formed from the dust, he is never referred to as the first born.  Jesus, however, was the first born of God's spirit and begotten of God.  He is called the first born in Hebrew 6:1. After he died, a brand, new creation is born out of him. And you are right he is called the second Adam, who is supreme over everything.

Comment: @David Jasurda. I was thinking about Ishmael being Abraham's first born son.  He was born of fleshy means.  He is not the one who inherited Abraham blessing.  It was through the promised seed of Isaac who became Abraham's official first born son.  This is through a promise of God that is counted as Abraham's first born.  The first born is associated with the greatest inheritance from the father.

Comment: The Bible does say Jesus is the Firstborn son of God. There is no Romans 12:36. Jesus was God in the flesh.   God did not need to repay Jesus for anything the two are one. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @David  Jasurda thanks for catching my mistake and I corrected it to Romans 11:35 and 36.

Comment: No Jesus is not called the second Adam. He is called the Last Adam. This is because as I mentioned before they are two people to have unblemished blood. Adam was created with unblemished blood and Jesus was born with unblemished blood. There will not be a second or third, fourth, fifth and so on. There is only a first Adam and a Last Adam. But    Jesus is called the second man and the was a third man and a fourth man and thousands of men after the second man. Yet was calling the first born. If I had more characters left I could explain in great detail how all this fits together as God planned

Answer (score 0):

Start with this portion of the text:

> He is the image of the invisible God,
>
> the firstborn over all creation.
>
> For everything was created by him,
>
> in heaven and on earth,
>
> the visible and the invisible,
>
> whether thrones or dominions  or rulers or authorities —
>
> all things have been created through him and for him.
>
> He is before all things,
>
> and by him all things hold together.

What's interesting about this passage is that the entire text I quoted is an exposition of the term "πρωτότοκος" (pro-TOH-toh-kos)"firstborn" in its philosophical meaning, and much of it is directed at/against a Gnostic understanding of "firstborn".

In the philosophical use, the word is used in the sense of "opener of the way" (or "way-opener").  The idea is that there is some sort of barrier -- in this passage the "barrier" between non-existence and creation -- and the 'firstborn' forges an opening through that barrier so that others may follow.  This means that everything coming through the barrier, i.e. into existence, is formed or shaped by the Way-opener, thus "everything was created by Him". The next two lines are commentary on "everything", to make clear that nothing is left out; this is followed by a line listing things that Gnostics considered important (but were also important in the view of spiritual hierarchy as understood by second Temple Judaism).  Then there's a return to expounding the term "firstborn": "all things have been created through Him and for Him", emphasizing that because they "crossed the barrier" into existence they are His, they are "for Him".
"He is before all things" is true because the Way-opener has to pass the barrier ahead of everything else.  Finally, since He is the opener of the way into existence, He is also the one who holds everything in existence.

Does this make the Firstborn "supreme"?  Though philosophers spoke more of preeminence, the answer is nevertheless a clear "Yes!" because He is unique:  He opened the way into existence so that everything that exists is shaped by Him, belong to Him, and are held in existence by Him.

It doesn't matter that the Firstborn, Jesus, didn't take on material form until some time after the creation of the universe or the world; to take the philosophical implication here it was the fact that God the Son would become flesh that made all the rest possible.  As the Apostle wrote, "apart from Him was nothing made that has been made".

A huge implication is that everything takes on the "shape" of Jesus.  That means that whatever you look at, whether a blade of grass or a bird in the air or a dolphin or for that matter even a table, in some way tells about Jesus.

And now for the rest of the passage:

> He is also the head of the body, the church;
>
> he is the beginning,
>
> the firstborn from the dead,
>
> so that he might come to have
>
> first place in everything.

Just in case the reader might have only been thinking about the realm of the living, the hymn (this is recognized as being one of the very first Christian hymns) applies the title of Firstborn to the realm of the dead as well, making sure that we know that He has "first place in everything". Again He is the Way-opener, making a passage from Sheol to resurrection life, a Way for us to follow.

And between these two sections, one about the realm of the living and the other about the realm of the dead, the hymn assures us that this Firstborn is our Head, the head of the church.

But we shouldn't leave out the rest of the hymn:

> For God was pleased to have
>
> all his fullness dwell in him,
>
> and through him to reconcile
>
> everything to himself,
>
> whether things on earth or things in heaven,
>
> by making peace
>
> through his blood shed on the cross.

"Fullness" is a Gnostic term, "τὸ πλήρωμα" (to PLAY-row-ma) used to describe God in Himself, that He has/is everything that is good, has all power, etc. so nothing is lacking.  But to the Gnostic this can't apply to the material realm and most certainly not to any human, so when Paul says "God was pleased to have all His fullness dwell in Him (Jesus) he is effectively slapping them in the face with the assertion that whatever God is, Jesus is, and thus that God didn't reserve anything, didn't hold anything back when He became man.
"Everything" in the next line is "τὰ πάντα" (tah PAHN-tah), which is itself a bit of a technical term that mean "the all", i.e. the whole show, everything that is -- it reaches back to the same term in verse 16 except now the Way-opener isn't creating everything, He's reconciling it to Himself, which is to say that everything that has gone astray along with anything that didn't go astray are gathered as one in peace (shalom) with God.  And that peace comes "through His blood shed on the Cross".

That fleshes out the import of "firstborn" because peace with God is a Way that He opened.